# Webservice WS-Security namespace of Type attribute

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, ws-security

I make a request to an external webservice using WS-Security. Form SoapUI it all works fine. From .Net (C#) it does not.

I found the difference in the request is the namespace of the Type attribute in the Security header.

From soapUI the header contains:

```
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-90bae2a1-88a9-4b4c-b84e-9244d3576051-7">
            <o:Username>******</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
```

from .net (C#) the xml is like:

```
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-90bae2a1-88a9-4b4c-b84e-9244d3576051-7">
            <o:Username>******</o:Username>
            <o:Password o:Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
```

The problem is the server is not accepting the o: in the Type attribute of the password element.

First of all: Should the server accept the o: in the Type attribute?

Second (and more important): is there a way to remove o: from the Type attribute since I don't have control over the webservice?

In C# I use a basicHttpBinding with TransportWithMessageCredential security mode.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a thread on Connect](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4df3354f-0627-42d9-b5fb-6e880b60f8ee/non-schema-compliant-wsse-username-token-created?forum=wcf) - from 8 years ago! - which references the same issue:

> When my application server tries to validate this, it fails with a
>   message about the Type attribute on Password.  The presence of a
>   namespace declaration seems to cause schema validation failure.

The response is:

> WCF is unfortunately generating the token improperly. A bug has been
>   filed for this.
>
> You have a couple options for workarounds
>
> 1) Easier—set `WSSecurityTokenSerializer.EmitsBspRequiredAttribute =
>   false`. This will suppress the Type attribute altogether, in which case
>   it defaults to
>
> http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText.
>   That's what your currently specifying, but you'll need to be sure the
>   service expects that default and won't need to specify anything else.
>
> 2) Harder—write a custom serializer for the Username token to correct
>   this behavior.

There's an example of a serializer later in the thread.